# How to Remove all Instances of edit_post_link

Tags: php, pages, theme-twenty-eleven

Can someone please assist with how to remove from my theme, whilst in author mode, the edit_post_link (Edit link), throughout all my pages. Which php files in the Twenty Eleven theme (WordPress v3.2) do I need to comment out to no longer display this edit link?

I realise that you only see this during author mode but would like to know how to remove altogether.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [`edit_post_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link) function. You'll find lines like the following, that you need to comment out:

```
// from /twentyeleven/content-intro.php
edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' );
```

Answer (score 14):

One way is to edit the template files of your theme, as you mentioned in your question you are using Twenty Eleven, so you can follow the advice of **@kaiser**.

The other way that I will prefer instead of modifying the template files is to use the filter. The advantage of filter is it will work with other themes too. The disadvantage of filter is that you will have empty `<span></span>` tags in your html source, though they won't be visible on the actual page.

You can put the following code in your functions.php.

```
function wpse_remove_edit_post_link( $link ) {
    return '';
}
add_filter('edit_post_link', 'wpse_remove_edit_post_link');
```

P.S you can use the filter to disable the edit post link on selective posts too.

Comment: Or just use `add_filter( 'edit_post_link', '__return_false' );` :)

Comment: Would `add_filter( 'edit_post_link', '__return_null' );` be more appropriate than false?

Comment: This is better than the accepted solution because you don't need to look for the actual function, which is especially difficult if you use child themes.

Answer (score 5):

Hameedullah's answer is more elegant, but doesn't eliminate the before and after items.  To do that, you need to filter get_edit_post_link instead, and return null.

```
function wpse_remove_get_edit_post_link( $link ) {
    return null;
}
add_filter('get_edit_post_link', 'wpse_remove_get_edit_post_link');
```

Comment: this also kills the edit link in the admin area!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner. `add_filter('edit_post_link', '__return_false');`
Bonus: Hide admin bar `add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');`

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the edit post link from those who aren't administrators.

```
// Hide the Edit Post Link from Non Administrators Start.

function prefix_remove_get_edit_post_link( $link ) {
    if(current_user_can('administrator')) {
        return $link;
    }
    return null;
}

add_filter('get_edit_post_link', 'prefix_remove_get_edit_post_link');

// Hide the Edit Post Link from Non Administrators End.
```